# Python NameError: Name 'get_tool_versions' not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to run a cmd script which calls a `setenv.py` file. This file has a function which says,

```
    import build_cfg
    tool_versions = get_tool_versions()
    env_var_list = get_env_var()
```

which I believe is importing the `build_cfg` module.
`build_cfg` in turn has `get_tool_versions` and `get_env_vars` functions defined.

Anyway, when I run my script I get an error :

```
File "setenv.py", line 172, in <module>
   tool_versions = get_tool_versions ()
NameError: name 'get_tool_versions' is not defined
```

I am relatively new to python. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `get_tool_versions ()` I suspect you want to get rid of the space: `get_tool_versions()`

Comment: Thanks but I tried that. Didn't work

Comment: `build_cfg.get_tool_versions()` and `build_cfg.get_env_var()`, then

Comment: Shouldn't be `build_cfg.get_tool_version()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all: The function `get_tool_versions` does not exist in the global [namespace](http://www.python-course.eu/namespaces.php).
To solve this problem you have to find out where `get_tool_versions` is defined and import it from there. If it is defined in `build_cfg` you can do it like this:

```
import build_cfg
tool_versions = build_cfg.get_tool_versions()
...
```

or

```
from build_cfg import get_tool_versions
tool_versions = get_tool_versions()
...
```